# How to break table at end of page

Tags: tables, longtable

I have the following table representing my acronyms. Due to the length of the table, the table does not break at the end of the page.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, draft, oneside]{book}

\begin{document}
\section*{Acronyms}
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{ll}
2D            & 2-Dimentional \\[2ex]
3D            & 3-Dimentional \\[2ex]
BA            & Bundle Adjustment \\[2ex]
CRF           & Conditional Random Field \\[2ex]
DLT           & Direct Linear Transformation \\[2ex]
DOF           & Degrees of Freedom \\[2ex]
DPM           & Deformable Part Model \\[2ex]
EO            & Exterior Orientation \\[2ex]
EP\textit{n}P & Efficient Perspective-$n$-Point Algorithm \\[2ex]
FOV           & Field of View \\[2ex]
FPS           & Frames per Second \\[2ex]
GCP           & Ground Control Point \\[2ex]
HOG           & Histogram of Orientated Gradients \\[2ex]
ICP           & Iterative Closest Point \\[2ex]
IO            & Interior Orientation \\[2ex]
IP            & Infrared \\[2ex]
iif           & if and only if \\[2ex]
i.i.d         & independent and identically distributed \\[2ex]
LM            & Levenberg-Marquardt \\[2ex]
LS            & Least-Squares \\[2ex]
MRF           & Markov Random Field \\[2ex]
MVEE          & Minimum Volume Enclosing Ellipsoid \\[2ex]
P\textit{n}P  & Perspective-$n$-Point Algorithm \\[2ex]
PCA           & Principal Component Analysis \\[2ex]
RMS           & Residual Mean Square Error \\[2ex]
SSVM          & Structured Support Vector Machine \\[2ex]
SVM           & Support Vector Machine
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you have tagged this longtable but not used that package, `table` and `tabular` do not break, delete `table` and change `tabular` to `longtable`  although that may be better set as a list rather than a table.

Comment: Additionally have a look at the glossaries package